# Writing data into an Excel spreadsheet - why does it skip every second line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, openpyxl

I'm using openpyxl in Python to copy some data from a txt file into an Excel spreadsheet. The following code, however simple, is skipping every second line though, and is only writing to every other line in the spreadsheet. Can someone help and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
line_index = 1  # To keep track of the current line's "index" in the file
    for l in f:
        line = l.split(",")

    # Transfer needed values into Spreadsheet, leaving the first two columns
    # empty so they can be populated later, because openpyxl doesn't support
    # easy insertion of columns.
        for i in range(len(line)):
            ws.cell(row=line_index, column=i+3).value = line[i]            
        line_index += 1
```

Comment: Printing an example of this in pure python results in the expected output. Can you show an example of *your* output?

Comment: My test can be found [here](https://repl.it/repls/BurlywoodOffbeatLion)

Comment: Are you certain that your text file doesn't have any blank lines?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you need a counter use the `enumerate()` function for reliability. Secondly, rather than calling `ws.cell()` just prepend the line with two empty values `[None]*2` so that you can use `ws.append()`. And, thirdly, openpyxl v2.5 does support column and row inserts and deletes.

```
TWO_COLS = [None] * 2
for line in f:
    line = TWO_COLS + line.split()
    ws.append(line)
```